# Problemas con repositorio GIT (no deja hacer push)

Tags: git, github, git-push

Tengo un proyecto descargado directamente desde el **PhpStorm** directamente desde el VC (version control), hasta aquí todo bien, me deja trabajar pero cuando voy a hacer cambios solo me hace el commit y me dice push failed.

Por lo que veo me añade una barra al final de la ruta del proyecto, es decir **https://github.com/repo/proyecto.git/** por lo que esa barra después del .git me provoca conflicto.

Me he metido dentro de la carpeta **.git** del proyecto a nivel local y me he metido en el archivo de configuración, pero por lo que veo esta todo correctamente, alguien sabría decirme si el fallo viene de ahí o si podría haber otro causante?

Aqui dejo el contenido del fichero de configuración:

```
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = false
        logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
        url = https://github.com/repo/proyecto.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Al escribir el comando **git config remote.origin.url** me muestra la ruta correctamente sin la barra final.

Comment: hay varias cosas por las que puede dar failed, para empezar por las credenciales, pero pon el mensaje de error para que podamos contestarte.

Comment: Algunas preguntas, el push lo estás haciendo con PhpStorm o con la terminal?, que sale en terminal al hacer git remote -v show (recuerda hacer antes git init dentro de la carpeta del proyecto) y por último qué otra cosa sale en el log de error?

Comment: creo que esto te puede ayudar http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/27760/4617

Answer (score 0):

La url de origin esta en la forma https, prueba a usar la forma ssh y tener las credenciales ssh.

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:repo/proyecto.git
```

Si no tienes las credenciales shh : https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/