# Error al actualizar mi repositorio remoto en Git hub

Tags: git, github, git-push

Tengo el siguiente error al actualizar mi repositorio remoto a git hub

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mvc>git push
remote: Permission to otrousuario/mvc.git denied to usuario.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/otrousuario/mvc.git/': The    requested URL returned error: 403
```

cuando verifico mi estado en remoto

```
git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/otrousuario/mvc.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/otrousuario/mvc.git (push)
```

Soy nuevo en esto de repositorios en .git, espero puedan ayudarme

**Nota** Esos dos usuario son dos cuentas que tengo, pero al parecer no me pide el usuario y contraseña del usuario "otro-usuario", se podra hacer tambien que sepa a quien usuario quiero hacer el push

Comment: entra desde git con interface e inicia sesion con tu otro usuario

Comment: me podrias explicar como hacerlo?

Comment: click en la rueda de configuracion e ir a opciones

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buenas.
Al parecer GitHub no soporta escritura por medio del protocolo Https, solo SSH.

Debes cambiar la dirección de tu repositorio remoto de la siguiente manera: [[Changing remote's url](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)]

```
git remote set-url <name> git@github.com:<username>/<repo>.git
```

donde `<name>` es el nombre del repositorio remoto (en tu caso es origin), por lo tanto debería quedar algo asi:

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:otrousuario/mvc.git
```

También puedes hacerlo editando el archivo **".git/config"** en el directorio donde está tu repositorio local.

- Busca `url=[...]` en donde dice `[remote "origin"]`
- Cambialo de `url=https://github.com/otrousuario/mvc.git` a `url=ssh://git@github.com/otrousuario/mvc.git`.
- Guarda el archivo de configuracion.

Ahora puedes hacer *"push"* al repositorio remoto. Si no posees una clave SSH debes crear una usando el comando `ssh-keygen`[[Generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-an-ssh-key/)] en la consola de git. Luego debes agregar la clave publica a tu perfil de Github.

Puedes encontrar mas información en los siguientes enlaces:

[Empezando con Git](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Empezando-Configurando-Git-por-primera-vez)
[Repositorios remotos](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Fundamentos-de-Git-Trabajando-con-repositorios-remotos)
[Error 403 with Git over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7438313/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed)
[Generar clave SSH](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Git-en-un-servidor-Generando-tu-clave-p%C3%BAblica-SSH)